# Okay, unidiomatisch oder falsch - "ich" am Satzende

Tags: sentence-structure

In einem Artikel über deutsche Wortstellung habe ich neulich folgendes Beispiel verwendet

> Das Buch gebe dir heute ich.

Diese Satzstellung ist natürlich ungewöhnlich und selten. Sie ist extrem stark markiert, braucht eine spezifische Betonung und macht nur Sinn, wenn ich "Ich" extrem betonen und eventuell einen Anschluss zum nächsten Satz schaffen will

> Das Buch gebe dir heute ich, und nicht mein Bruder.

@CarstenSchulz hat argumentiert, dass dieser Satz für ihn falsch klingt und ein so spätes Subjekt in diesem Kontext nur in der dritten Person funktioniert.
Für mich klingt er richtig, ist auch grammatisch korrekt und gehört in eine Reihe mit Sätzen wie diesen:

> Die Feinabstimmung übernehme zur Sicherheit diesmal ich.
>
> Den Müll runterbringen musst heute ausnahmsweise mal du.

- Ist der Satzbau grammatisch richtig?
- Klingt er nur für mich richtig?

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach klingt der erste Satz auch falsch, auch wenn man ihn "extrem" betont. Vielleicht, weil das Objekt ("dir") vor dem Subjekt liegt?

Comment: @splattne... das ist in der dritten Person auch der Fall "Die Tests gibt euch morgen der Thomas zurück."

Comment: Für mich klingt es richtig, vielleicht handelt es sich um eine Art Dialekt? (Süddeutschland)

Comment: Hm, je öfter ich es lese, desto richtiger klingt es. :-) Aber trotzdem würde ich sicher *Das Buch gebe **ich** dir heute* sagen.

Comment: @Pasoe... ich bin Berliner. Also wohl eher nicht regional.

Comment: @splattne... ja, keine Frage, dass das nicht die erste Wahl ist. Aber halt nicht falsch wie ""Das Buch ich gebe dir heute."

Comment: Der Satz ist völlig in Ordnung. Wird ganz normal verwendet, um "ich" stark zu betonen. Im Deutschen kann man alles verdrehen, das ist ja das Flexible. Durch die Fälle, in die die Satzglieder gesetzt werden, bleibt der Sinn klar. Im Englischen ist man i.d.R. auf SPO festgelegt; da unsere 4 Fälle fehlen, geht das da also nicht anders.

Comment: Es funktioniert natürlich nur mit der richtigen Betonung, aber in der richtigen Situation kann man das schon sagen. Ich finde aber, dass die beiden anderen Beispiele natürlicher klingen (möglicherweise weil man die wohl auch öfter benutzt). Es könnte vielleicht dadran liegen, dass das ich so weit vom gebe weg ist und das irgendwie normalerweise näher zusammenliegt. Solange man nur Adverbiale (oder wie das heißt) dazwischenbaut stört es nicht, aber sobald da so etwas wie ein Objekt dazwischenkommt, fühlt sich das für den ein oder anderen komisch an.

Comment: Für mich klingt es mal mehr und mal weniger falsch. Auf jeden Fall finde ich es gut, dass Du das hier fragst.

Comment: Wenn der Satz alleine steht, klingt das ganze ein bisschen nach Yoda ;) Mit Nebensatz (oder im entsprechenden Kontext) und entsprechender Betonung könnte ich ihn mir dagegen durchaus vorstellen.

Comment: "Heute gebe ich Dir das Buch."
ist viel gebräuchlicher und betont dass es (heute) eine einmalige Ausnahme ist.

Allerdings sollte Dein Vorschlag dennoch grammatikalisch korrekt sein

Comment: @sebweisgerber.. für mein Empfinden betont dein Satz garnichts speziell. er ist einfach nur normal.

Answer (score 5):

Man kann sich durch den Satz durchbeißen. Dass er jedoch recht ungewöhnlich angeordnet ist, sieht man, wenn man *heute* weglässt:

> Das Buch gebe dir ich.

Aber auch hier überlebt der Satz mMn, wenn man *ich* stärker markiert. Diese Freiheit scheint mir nur in gesprochener Sprache zu existieren.

Ein Artikel von "Belles Lettres beschäftigt sich mit diesem Thema und bietet auch zwei Direktiven dazu an (aber leider nur für die Reihenfolge in Nebensätzen, wenn man's genau nimmt):

> **Obere Direktive** Das Kürzere steht vor dem Längeren. Weil Re­flexiv­pronomina und Per­sonal­prono­mina grundsätzlich kürzer sind als Substantive, stehen Pro­nomina vor Substan­tiven.
>
> **Untere Direktive** Das Subjekt steht vor dem Objekt.
>
> Die untere Direktive gilt nur, wenn beide Satzglieder entweder Sub­stan­tive oder Pronomina sind.

Der letzte Satz trifft auf unser Beispiel zu, wonach die infrage stehende Reihenfolge falsch wäre (sofern man dieselben Regeln für Hauptsätze annimmt). Man könnte eventuell versuchen, es unter die angeführten [Ausnahmen](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/wortstellung-reflexivpronomen-personalpronomen.php) zu bringen. Die Kombination beider Direktiven deckt sich außerdem mit der Aussage unter der Tabelle in [diesem Artikel](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau/hauptsaetze).

Es kommt jedoch hinzu, dass der Fall mit einem zwischenstehenden Adverb nicht behandelt wird, wie es im eigentlichen Beispiel der Fall ist. Somit lässt sich mithilfe dieser Artikel kein wirklich eindeutiger Schluss fassen.

Abschließend sei angemerkt, dass das Beispiel semantisch eindeutig ist. Solange die Richtigkeit der Reihenfolge also nicht anderweitig widerlegt wird, bleibt sie wohl lediglich ungewohnt.

Answer (score 0):

Mir scheint, neben den bereits von @CarstenSchulz genannten Beispielen gibt es andere (kurze) idiomatische Sätze, wo das "ich" oder "du" am Ende steht.

"Das mach ich!"

"(Den) hast du!" oder "Nimm du!" (Fussball)

Comment: Stimmt aber in diesen Beispielen ist das Zufall, da es keine weiteren Element gibt. Nimm im ersten Satz "morgen" und bei "Nimm du" das Wort "das" dazu und guck, wo du sie hinstecken wrdest. Dann siehst du, dass das Pronomen nicht wirklich am Ende ist. Also schon, aber mit den Beispielen in der Frage nicht zu vergleichen.